# converting Roman numerals into decimal

Tags: c++, decimal, roman-numerals

Hey guys I think I'm really close with but I'm not too sure how to continue. All of the questions related to my problem don't really answer anything. The error that I'm getting right now is an

```
(33): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
(41): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

**Header file:**

```
using namespace std;

class romanType
{
public: 
    void printRoman(char romanNum);
    int printDecimal(int& total);
    int convertRoman(int& total);
    void setRoman(char& roman);

    romanType();
    romanType(char);

private:
    char romanNum[6];
    int decimal;
    int total;
};
```

**Implementation:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "romanType.h" 

using namespace std;

romanType::romanType(char)
{

};
void romanType::printRoman(char romanNum)
{
    cout << "Here is your number in Roman Numeral form: " << romanNum << endl;
};

int romanType::printDecimal(int& total)
{
    cout << "Here is your number in Decimal form: " << total << endl;
    return total;
};

void romanType::setRoman(char& romanNum)
{

};
int romanType::convertRoman(int& total)
{
    int len = 0;
    len = strlen(romanNum);
    int count[1];

     for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
     {           
           switch(romanNum[i])
           {
                 case 'M':
                      count[i] = 1000;
                      break;
                 case 'm':
                      count[i] = 1000;
                      break;
                 case 'D':
                      count[i] = 500;
                      break;
                 case 'd':
                      count[i] = 500;
                      break;
                 case 'C':
                      count[i] = 100;
                      break;
                 case 'c':
                      count[i] = 100;
                      break;
                 case 'L':
                      count[i] = 50;
                      break;
                 case 'l':
                      count[i] = 50;
                      break;
                 case 'X':
                      count[i] = 10;
                      break;
                 case 'x':
                      count[i] = 10;
                      break;
                 case 'V':
                      count[i] = 5;
                      break;
                 case 'v':
                      count[i] = 5;
                      break;
                 case 'I':
                      count[i] = 1;
                      break;
                 case 'i':
                      count[i] = 1;
                      break;
                 default:
                      cout << "Error.." << endl;
           }   
           total = total + count[0];
     }
     return total;
};
```

**My main:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "romanType.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    romanType r;

    char romanNum;
    char choice;
    int decimal;
    int total;

    cout << "Hello! Please enter your Roman Numeral: " << endl; 
    cin >> romanNum; 
    cout << endl;


    r.setRoman(romanNum);
    r.convertRoman(total);

    cout << "Do you want the Roman Numeral or the Decimal?" << endl;
    cout << "Press [D] for Decimal!" << endl << "Press [R] for Roman Numeral!" << endl;

    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 'D' || choice == 'd')
         r.printDecimal(total);
    else if (choice == 'R' || choice == 'r')
         r.printRoman(romanNum);
    else
        cout << "That wasn't the right button!" << endl;

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm on the right track. It would be nice to see any tips or advice relating to my errors.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Which are lines 33 and 41?

Comment: Btw the problem is Write a program that converts a number entered in Roman Numerals to decimal. Needs to consist of a class called romanType and an object that does the following:

Store the number as a Roman numeral
Convert and store the number into decimal form
Print the number as a Roman numeral or decimal number as requested by user

The decimal values of the roman numerals are:
M = 1000
D = 500
C = 100
L = 50
X = 10
V = 5
I = 1

Comment: r.convertRoman(total); and r.printDecimal(total);

Comment: Roman numerals are reverse-accumulated. You start with the *right* end, adding values as long as they are increasing or equal in value, then subtracting *from* that accumulation when you encounter a numeral *smaller* than the previous numeral.

Comment: Your program only works with a single Roman digit, not a whole Roman number. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Further, the symptoms you're describing suggest your code is compiling with a *different* header than the one you're showing here. Perhaps an old copy or perhaps you didn't save the file after updating it prior to compiling. Also, you declare, but never *define* the `romanType::romanType()` constructor. It is in the header file, but nowhere in the implementation files.

Comment: `r.convertRoman(total);` here `total` is uninitialized.

Comment: Are those compiler errors? I was able to get it to compile (once I defined the undefined `romanType::romanType()`). So @WhozCraig is on to something...

Comment: This line is clearly wrong, but not the error you're getting: `len = strlen(romanNum);` strlen() requires a `char*` as the argument, but `romanNum` is a `char`.

Answer (score -1):

From just a quick look at the code, I might suggest looking through the debug window at the values of your variables at each step. What I am seeing is two variables, one char type named romanNum, and an entirely different one that is a char array named romanNum. It gets a little confusing but could work if you are only asking the user for a single char in roman numerals which then you wouldn't need an array at all. Otherwise, you could get a string then convert that into an array.

Start there and see if that helps.

Comment: The OP is getting compiler errors. They kinda can't look into the debug window without compiling first...